# How to write to a text file on a USB flash drive on boot linux?

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, autostart

I want to create a text file in a USB flash drive and write to it from a python script . this has happen everytime on autostart (crontab) too. Can anyone tell me how to this?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Its more like a statement then a question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you sure don't want to use crontab -- that will run on a time-wise schedule.

You probably would have a better time appending your write-script logic (or an execution of your write-script) to the `rc.local` script in `/etc` (actually, I forget if it's in `/etc` or `/etc/rc.d` on rasperian...

Oh look! Rasperrypi.org has a link to do just that!  How convieeeeeenient!

http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md